# Can moderators use their default username?

Tags: support, moderators, display-names

I just came across a question that was closed by a moderator (♦)
However, said (currently active) moderator just has a default (`user<number>`) username that matches their user ID.

Seeing as the account has over 200k rep, and is over a decade old, it's obviously someone that has earned their stripes on SO.
However, as moderators are elected by the community, shouldn't they be identifiable as being the same user you might've once voted for?

(I'm deliberately not naming the user here, they're not necessarily doing anything "wrong")

Comment: So we're talking about [user229044](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/user229044)? Who both appears on the [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) page, and was elected in 2015? I don't see the problem here; we're free to chose our display names here; if that display name is the default (like the user here), an alias (like myself), or your real name doesn't matter.

Comment: so, they're not anonymous, they just go by a default-like name, that's been a thing for quite a while.

Comment: Why does it matter that someone (moderator or not) changing their display name? That doesn't make them a different person. I've been tempted to change from my Alias to my name for years, I just haven't done it because I've *always* been Larnu here; that doesn't mean I'm not allowed to and I don't see why being a moderator doesn't allow them to change their name.

Comment: I really fail to see the problem. Mods, like regular users, aren't required to stand forward with a full name and ID (hyperbole) just because they're mods, and we're still allowed to use aliases or nicknames (or just bog-standard usernames). I'll spare the reiteration of how `user1234` isn't anonymous; Dharman covered that solidly already. It's an actual account belonging to a single, specific mod, who decided to anonymize their profile. I cannot answer why (I don't know why), but it doesn't matter either

Comment: User IDs also remain constant even though usernames don't. If you're not sure, you can always revisit the election page

Comment: AFAIK I never agreed to use any particular username, either implicitly or explicitly when I ran in the moderator election.

Comment: Regarding anonymity: If all mods were to use their default username, I’d argue they’d be difficult to distinguish. Again, this is just a honest question, I’m not saying they’re being bad mods, and I’m certainly not implying they’re breaking any promises or rules. I just thought it was curious, and my personal preference would be for mods to use a more personal name <3

Comment: I guess it would have some benefit for when moderator actions are put up for discussion on meta. I can't speak for others but I won't be able to remember what user32321 and user23321 did so I wouldn't be able to remember if what is said about them is truthful or falsehood. That is pretty much all I can come up with where having a uniquely identifiable fake name *for the human brain* has some benefit. And a small benefit it is, such meta posts are usually created out of anger and not to have a discussion.

Comment: You presume that moderators need to be distinguished, @Cerbrus. Why?

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't "presume", and I'm not claiming they "need" to be. Again, this is just a question about something I found curious. That said, I'd love to be able to recognize a moderator in repeat interactions, and tell them they're doing good work. Mods don't get appreciated nearly enough on SE. That recognizing is easier with "custom" names. Now, on the flipside I understand users with malicious intent might use it to the opposite effect, but then again, most more drastic mod actions are truly anonymous, any way.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the [moderators page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) contains a link to the election in which each mod was elected. For user229044 this is https://stackoverflow.com/election/6 where you see their user presentation, with their then-username visible at the top of their pitch.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Having a username in the format "user<number>" doesn't make them anonymous. On the contrary, this is their username, which means they are identifiable.

Moderators, just like anyone else, are free to change their username to whatever they like (within the constraints of CoC). If I wanted to be called "The magnificent deletor" from now on, you can't say I am being anonymous, but rather that I decided to change my username. Same with usernames such as "user<number>". The person operating the account is still the same; they just go by a different name now.

Comment: Thanks @Dharman! I still think it might be easier to remember an (for lack of a better word) "real" name, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: @Cerbrus FWIW the only real hassle I've ever had with this is for moderators trying to superping in chat (which searches by username). It usually necessitates a trip to the Mods page for copy-pasta. But I run into the same problem [even if they just pick an unconventional name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541136/russia-must-remove-putin). It's pretty uncommon we need to superping anyone, tho, let alone a fellow mod.

Comment: Don't forget the [who are these people and when were they elected?](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) page.